# Return an external file in SQL result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, blob

I need to develop a web service to make some files available on an external web site. These files are kept and updated on a file server with their UNC paths in a database. The web service will be hosted on a server in our DMZ and has access to the database but not to the file shares.

The options I see are:

1. Upload the documents to the web server. That's difficult without LAN access.
2. Write an additional process to upload the files into the database and serve them from there. This causes extra work everywhere but is probably acceptable.
3. Find some way for a stored procedure to read the files from the network share and return them in a result set that may be used by the web service.

Does anyone know how I could go about option 3? I suspect I'll need to upload it into a blob and read that in the web service, but is it even possible to load a file into a blob using only SQL?

Update:
I found [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) and copied the ufsReadfileAsString function. I keep getting "error while opening file" errors which I think may be related to user permissions.

Comment: Which kind of file do you want to read? If an OLEDb provider exists for your files you could do the option 3 with Linked Servers and OPENROWSET.

Comment: It's a binary file, so no rowset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, nearly four years later I had another look at it. It turns out this is really simple!

```
declare @myFile varchar(max)

select @myFile = BulkColumn
from openrowset(bulk'C:\Path\To\File\Test.txt', single_blob) x;

select @myFile
```

The fly in the ointment is obviously file permissions, but once you have that sorted, this works well.

Comment: Nearly 7 years later, here is your first upvote. To be honest I've not seen it in action because I havent got permission but it looks promising enough.